# jQuery pagination in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, pagination

How to create a jQuery pagination in CodeIgniter?

Please give me an example of it.

I would not like to use a plugin, because the code plugin is large. Is there a way to reach this with less code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out [TOHIN](http://tohin.wordpress.com/2008/08/12/codeigniter-ajax-pagination/) example pagination with ajax ,Or work around [GOOGLE](http://www.google.com.eg/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+and+CI+pagination)

Comment: i not know how must use of TOHIN. did you can tell me example?

Comment: **There is a PHP library in CI** you can integrate with jquery ajax calls to implement the pagination you want with built-in library it'll be better i think.[CodeIgniter Pagination](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are a [number](http://www.enfew.com/8-best-tutorials-on-how-to-create-pagination-in-codeigniter/) [of](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-pagination/) [tutorials](http://www.thetutorialblog.com/php/twitter-like-pagination-using-codeigniter-and-jquery/) out there which explain how one might do this. It is a bit much to be able to fit it all here.

As to plugin size, I'm not certain how you came to that conclusion. Just because it is a plugin does not mean that it is large or cumbersome. It can be argued, rather easily, that CodeIgniter itself is just a large series of plugins...